# How to create popup button in bootstrap using card?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I am struggling to create a dashboard card that looks like image below.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to find a way around creating a dashboard that will load this modal form so it can display as a card with a publish button, image folder etc.

Here's what I tried:

```html
<center>
  <div class="ic-Dashboard-header_layout">
    <h1 class="ic-Dashboard-header_title">    
      <span class="hidden-phone">Dashboard</span>    
    </h1>
    <!---Some extra button here-->  
  </div>
  <!--Dashboard card here-->  
  <div class="main">
    <!--cards -->  
    <div class="card">
      <div class="image">    
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Gfp-missouri-st-louis-clubhouse-pond-and-scenery.jpg/1199px-Gfp-missouri-st-louis-clubhouse-pond-and-scenery.jpg">    
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>    
          Write title Here    
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="des">
        <p>You can Add Desccription Here...</p>
        <button>Read More...</button>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--cards -->    
  <!--Content page header-->  
  <section class="content-header-fluid">    
  </section>
</center>
```

Comment: why use bootstrap cards : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: Whole question is far too broad. Be more specific about parts you are stuck on

Comment: @charlitfl what i want to produce the same mock up, but my logic i posted here is not functional as compared to that card. When a user clicks the 'start course must produce that card. I believe there some functionality like jquery involved that calls that card to popup. I had a look for canvas documentation but was not successfully. Hope make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried bootstrap modal??
It will act the same as a "card" but in a popup window that shows in when you click a button.. exactly as u need
Check this link to the direct documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

here is a complete example

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```